# Write a Binding Greeter

Tags: code-golf

You will write a Program which writes the Second Program.

Each program has one Input; which may be a command line argument, or be read from stdin.  A Input is a single word made up of upper and/or lowercase letters (a-z)

Each program has Output; which may be to a file, or to stdout.

The Program (which you post here)

- accepts the Input Greeting, e.g. "Hello"
- the Output contains the source code of another program, which is described below

The Second Program

- accepts a Input of Name, e.g. "John"
- MUST NOT contain the Greeting in a format that could be read by an average computer programmer
- when executed makes the Output in the format of `{Greeting} {Name}`, e.g. "Hello John"
- MUST NOT use an encoding library or function, including but not limited to

  - base64/base32/baseN (unless manually implemented)
  - cryptography (unless manually implemented)

*"not be read by an average computer programmer"* is ambiguous, but here are some examples for the Greeting "Hello".  Use common sense, and I'll downvote if you do one of those *Well he didn't say "He" + "ll" + "o" was against the rules*

- Good

  - "Dqkta"
  - [9,3,5,1,6,1,5]
  - ↛↝↧
  - a^|12..7
  - ..--..--!!--.--.----.-,,--.
- Bad

  - "Hello"
  - "hEllo"
  - "h3110"
  - "He" + "llo"
  - ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
  - "H_e_l_l_o"

---

Scoring:

- usual codegolf, least bytes wins
- addition command line arguments cost the usual 1 point

  - no command line arguments allowed for the Second Program
- scoring only applies to the first Program (the one you post here)

Please also include an example generated program and a description.  If you're confused, see my example answer bellow.

Comment: is `"olleH"` good enough?

Comment: @JanDvorak Not if your layout settings are RTL ;-)

Comment: Nope.  Another way to look at it is, "Here's the Second Program; and here are 5 possible greetings that could be in it".  If someone could tell which of the 5 was used; it's not good enough.

Comment: Are the greetings mixed case, or can we just accept lowercase?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, letters of the alphabet and they can be upper or lowercase.  In Regular Expressions `[a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: No `"` in the greeting allowed? That would make this intresting.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, you can assume there will be only letters.  The user won't ever give invalid input.

Comment: A `!` would break both of your solutions. Would be more intresting to find a solution that works with all ascii chars or even unicode characters.

Comment: Does the second program need to be in the same language as the first?

Comment: @Johannes My solution works with all ASCII characters; it probably would work with Unicode but windows command prompt doesn't support Unicode :P so I can't test

Comment: @plannapus, nope :-)

Comment: How about conversion to ASCII characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### GolfScript, 15 / 11 characters

```
{)}%`'{(}%" "@'
```

Performs the same obfuscation as the example program. The resulting code for input `Howdy` is then

```
"Ipxez"{(}%" "@
```

For both programs input must be supplied on STDIN while output goes to STDOUT.

If it's ok to convert the string to codes only you can also take the 11 character solution

```
{}/32]`'\+'
```

(Thanks to Peter for an idea to save two more characters).

Comment: Wow, nice!  I was hoping it'd be a bit more difficult :-)  I probably should have picked a single difficult encoding, instead of just "unreadable".

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I didn't think that simple shifting was allowed and had a much more complex idea in mind before I read your example.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand And the difficult part is still to be done, namely beating the 12 character solution Peter will come around with in a few minutes.

Comment: Your 13-character solution can save two by replacing `" "+` with `32` before the `]`. I've only looked at this task briefly, and currently am lagging behind on 17.

Answer (score 6):

### APL(Dyalog), 16/20

Losing to GS again...

```
'⍞,⍨⊂⎕UCS',⎕UCS⍞
```

This may break the "no cryptography" rule. `⎕UCS` is a function to convert characters to unicode code points and back.

**Example**
First input: `Hello`
First output: `⍞,⍨⊂⎕UCS 72 101 108 108 111`
Second input: `John`
Second output: `Hello John` (Note the space before "Hello")

---

```
'⎕AV[','],⊂⍞',⍨⎕AV⍳⍞
```

Similar idea with the cryptography is manually implemented: Convert to/from index of some pre-defined character array (`⎕AV`) which includes all upper and lower alphabets.

Answer (score 3):

### Tcl, 111

```
puts "binary scan [join [lmap a [split $argv {}] {format %c [expr [scan $a %c]+256]}] {}]Ġ\$argv a* a;puts \$a"
```

Exploits the way how Tcl converts strings to bytearrays.

The output for `Howdy` is

```
binary scan ňůŷŤŹĠ$argv a* a;puts $a
```

Answer (score 3):

### R <s>113</s> <s>109</s> 97 characters

```
cat(unlist(sapply(utf8ToInt(scan(,"",n=1)),function(x)c(rep("+",x),".>"))),rep("+",32),".>+[,.]")
```

Takes an input as stdin and output a BrainF**k program that prints the input of the first program, a space and then takes a second input and output it, character by character, until an EOF character (or an empty input depending on the BF interpreter used).

Example output with first input `Salut`:

```
+ + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + .> + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + .> + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + .> + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + .> + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + .> + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + .>+[,.]
```

which you can test [here](http://brainfuck.tk/).
Initial input can include printable ASCII characters from `!` onwards (spaces don't work because by default `scan()` uses spaces as separators). Example for `$!"§&`:

```
+ + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + .> + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + .> + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + .> + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + .> + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + .> + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + .> + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + .>+[,.]
```

Comment: This is really cool!  I still can't rap my head around these stack languages.

Answer (score 3):

## Brainfuck <s>122 120 109</s> 106

```
+++++++[>++++++>+++++++++++++>++++<<<-]>+<,[[>.<-]>+++.>.<-.>++.--<--<,]>....>>[<<.>>-]<<+++.>.<--.++.>++.
```

Comment: +1 Neat, but could you explain some of the parts? I have trouble understanding why there is two times `,`. Also what it the purpose of this `><<`? Shouldn't it be just `<`?

Comment: @plannapus Sorry. I fogot to delete the `><` when I modified my code. The first `,` is to ensure that the byte at the pointer is nonzero.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example.  It's not competitive, but shows how it should work.  This is JavaScript which runs on Node.js

```
var i, charCode, Greeting = process.argv[2], obfuscated = '';

// We're just doing a regular upshift of characters
// a becomes b, etc.
for ( i = 0; i < Greeting.length; i++ ) {
    charCode = Greeting.charCodeAt(i);
    obfuscated += String.fromCharCode(charCode + 1);
}

// You'll want to compress this somehow
var code = [
    "var i, deObfuscated = '';", "var Name = process.argv[2];", "var Greeting = '" + obfuscated + "';",
    "for (i=0; i<Greeting.length; i++) {", "charCode = Greeting.charCodeAt(i);",
    "deObfuscated += String.fromCharCode(charCode - 1);}", "console.log(deObfuscated + ' ' + Name)"];

console.log(code.join('\n'));
```

I'll call this file Program.js.  It can be tested like so:

```
$ node Program.js Howdy > Second.js
$ node Second.js Partner
Howdy Partner
```

Second.js contains this.  Notice how "Howdy" doesn't appear visibly in this code.

```
var i, deObfuscated = '';
var Name = process.argv[2];
var Greeting = 'Ipxez';
for (i=0; i<Greeting.length; i++) {
charCode = Greeting.charCodeAt(i);
deObfuscated += String.fromCharCode(charCode - 1);}
console.log(deObfuscated + ' ' + Name)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 63

```
$><<"puts ''<<"+gets.chop.each_codepoint.to_a*'<<'+"<<' '+gets"
```

Output for `Hello`:

```
puts ''<<72<<101<<108<<108<<111<<' '+gets
```

Output for `asdfASDF1234!@#$<>,.`:

```
puts ''<<97<<115<<100<<102<<65<<83<<68<<70<<49<<50<<51<<52<<33<<64<<35<<36<<60<<62<<44<<46<<' '+gets
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 58 <del>61</del> <del>64</del> <del>74</del> Bytes

```
<?=0?~0 ." $argv[1]":strtr(file(__FILE__)[0],[~$argv[1]]);
```

The script replaces all `0` in its own source code with the inverted greeting. If run as `php greeter.php Hello`, the output is:

```
<?=ÀÜôôÉ?~ÀÜôôÉ ." $argv[1]":strtr(file(__FILE__)[ÀÜôôÉ],[~$argv[1]]);
```

If you run this as `php greeter2.php John`, the output with full error reporting is

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ÀÜôôÉ - assumed 'ÀÜôôÉ'
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ÀÜôôÉ - assumed 'ÀÜôôÉ'
Hello John
```

otherwise, just `Hello John`